# Trouble displaying associated records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I am working on a rails app that has two tables - customers and jobs.  A customer can have many jobs and each job belongs to a customer.  I have my associations set up and working accordingly.

I am having an issue displaying the jobs associated with customers.  Here is my code in the customer view:

```
<%= @customer.jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= job.id %>
<% end %>
```

All I wanted to do was test if this would output the job id's associated with this customer.  It does work, however, I get more than just the job id as output - here is what I see:

```
1 [#<Job id: 1, job_number: nil, installation: "Yes", install_date: "10/10/10", delivery: "Yes", box_count: 25, room_type: "Kitchen", material: "Maple", exterior_colour: "Ginger Root", created_at: "2014-07-29 18:41:25", updated_at: "2014-07-29 19:58:59", customer_id: 1>]
```

So you can see that it works, but I do not understand why I get the additional information associated with that job in [ ].

I'm sure my problem is related to naming, but this is the only version I have tried that does not throw an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do not understand why I get the additional information associated
>   with that job in [ ].

You have to remove `=` in this line

```
<%= @customer.jobs.each do |job| %>
```

It should be

```
<% @customer.jobs.each do |job| %>
```

A small note

```
<% %> #Executes the Ruby code.

<%= %> #Prints the output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<%` instead of `<%=` for the surrounding loop:

```
<% @customer.jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= job.id %>
<% end %>
```

`.each` executes the given block for each elements, and then **returns the object it just enumerated over**. Because of this, using `<%=` on the first line outputs the return value of `@customer.jobs.each`

Comment: Thank you, I did not know it would output that value!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to you go to app/db/schema.rb and look at the jobs table it will show all the fields related with that record. created_at and updated_at are created by default.